# Error with installing pr2-object-manipulation Stack

Tags: ros, household-objects-database, tabletop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on Ubuntu 11.10 with ROS Furete
I want to install tabletop_objects_detector package to use it with household_objects_database ,so I wrote this command in the terminal :
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-object-manipulation
unfortunately I got this error :
E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-pr2-object-manipulation
What should I do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57136/error-with-installing-pr2-object-manipulation-stack/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you have [setup your apt sources correctly.](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu#fuerte.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list)

The packages is present and available from the repository.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0